# VLAN support for ethernet on USB on android

Tags: android, network-programming, usb, ethernet

I am planning to develop a Ethernet test tool on android tablet. So I need the following information.

1. Does android has driver to access ethernet on USB port?
2. Does the driver has VLAN support?

I know that this is not a programming question. But I found nowhere else to get the answers for these queries. Please don't consider this as off-topic. It would be helpful for me, if I can get the details about above two.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit. Like which version of android, for USB<->ethernet driver do I need to install any app or its in-built into android kernel, to receive a vlan tagged ethernet packet and manipulate it, which android package I have to use?

Comment: I dont have much Idea on what kind of changes we need on kernel level. I think it should be inbuilt in to android kernel. at present I am working in a project where we have an android specific car board with 2.3.7 version and we have the access for the ethernet module over USB

Comment: thanks a lot raghav for the information. At least could you share what is the module name you use for "ethernet module over USB"

Comment: Its basically TRENDNET TU2-ET100

Comment: Thanks Raghav. If you insert the usb adapter, does it create an interface automatically? I mean how do you use the device you connected? Do the TrendNet provide the library API to develop and open sockets on that interface?

Comment: It creates an Interface automatically when we Insert usb adapter

Comment: Thanks Raghav. Did you test any VLAN traffic with this USB adapter?